# Does three month old labrador need a coat in winter?

Tags: dogs

I'm staying with step son who has a three month old labrador who has been kept inside all the time since owned two months ago. She's fully vaccinated but probably not fully socialized due to early separation from the litter.

I've been taking her for walks and she's happy to stand on ice but when she stops walking I notice her rear is shivering. I gather the breed are cold adapted even with a short coat, and apparently little subcutaneous fat. But it's minus 13 degrees Celsius outside, and since she's shivering, does she need a coat? We don't walk for more than an hour.

[image: lab puppy]

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7733/how-can-i-determine-the-temperature-when-my-dog-needs-to-wear-a-coat) which has a great answer and provides a tip about touching their ear. If you feel your question is different to that, please edit it to make the differences obvious. (Also - very cute dog)

Comment: Well body surface area is higher in pups so I think I'll get her a coat to wear to see if she'll stop wining.

Comment: @RebeccaRVT I can't join chat as it serves JavaScript from github which is blocked in China. Salt isn't used in Urumqi with snow clearing done manually by city workers. I'll give the coat a whirl.

Comment: There's no github JS afaik - and if users from china have an issue, I think the folks who run the network want to know about it, Mind posting about it on meta.stackexchange.com or on pets meta?

Comment: Sorry, misremembered it. It's Googleapis https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly

Comment: @Henders, I read the answer you pointed to me and found the reasoning implausible. The ears are not furthest from the heart, and are not a major area of heat loss. I found this answer on the web https://m.petmd.com/dog/care/how-cold-too-cold-dog but am not sure it's correct either although it seems to be a reputable site. The former answer appears to be an unreferenced personal opinion.

Comment: If the answers on that question don't meet your needs you could consider [placing a bounty](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on the question or researching your own answer and posting it there. The content of this question and the duplicate are asking about the same thing. A bounty is a way of drawing more attention to the question. You could also ask the OP for more details that may help. Thanks for your continued interest and enthusiasm! :)